# error finding <zlib.h> when compiling libpng via cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, libpng

I do have some difficulties compiling `libpng`

The `zlib` is not installed and I have to build from scratch

Since I don't have the privilege permission to access `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`, so I install `zlib` in `$HOME/zlib`

But when I try to build `libpng`, an error occurs, which says cannot find `<zlib.h>`

how to figure it out?

Comment: You need to change the `CMakeList.txt`to add `$HOME/zlib` to the include and library pathes.

Comment: Nope, you need to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `$HOME/zlib` when running CMake. It should then pick up your zlib.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your cmake following line

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/path/to/zlib/lib/pkgconfig")
```